# PHP parse navigation links on specific site by URL

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Ia am planning to get menu elements(links) from any given URL. That means the code should filter menu links (links that will be used to navigate inside the specific site) from all the other links that are present on the site.

I have been planning to use **simplehtmldom** as I have used it to parse content before.

**The problems:**

1. Menu link containers could be formatted differently: ul li, table or simple  tags inside divs.
2. Menu links can be images (the code should then use alt or title tags)

**My questions:**

1. Is there a possibility to somehow analyze the link content to make sure they are links?
   Etc. if the href has same domain name `href="http://domain.com/link"` or is local      `href="/link"`
2. How can I exclude language switch buttons as they are usually `domain.com/EN` or `en.doamin.com`? They are very similar to the real menu navigation links.

I hope you get the point.

Best,
Martti

Comment: `var_dump(filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));`

Comment: What theat code exactly does, Hanky Panky?

Answer (score 0):

this regex tests if a given string is or isnt an url:

```
^(http[s]?://|ftp://)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|ca|co.uk|com.au|gov|br)$
```

you could implement some preg_match tests... hope it helps

ref:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

[edit]

The variable $thePath should bring you the current site url:

```
$theProtocol = (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']), 'https') === false) ? 'http' : 'https';
$thePath = $theProtocol.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

So, you could compare the matching string with the variable content then determine if you're manipulating an internal link.

This shoud be helpful:

```
function str_starts_with($haystack, $needle, $caseSensitive = true){
        if($caseSensitive)
            return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
        else
            return stripos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I use simplehtmldom then I get the content by <a> or href so I already know they are all links. The question is to find out which of them are the links that are used to navigate inside the site.

Comment: I am using `// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';` to find all links on the page and `$parse = parse_url($url);
$scheme = $parse['scheme'];
$host = $parse['host'];` to get the domain and scheme. Now I need a function to filter out internal links.

Comment: I found this. Maybe you can tell how it might have been done http://gomobi.info/try-for-free/